# Why do my USB ports sometimes break?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

Once in a while, I have a weird issue with my HP EliteBook 1040: While I'm working, the USB port suddenly stops working. I have a single USB mouse connected to it. None of the other ports work. At the same time, the integrated webcam cannot be found. The rest still works. So far, a restart fixed this.

As a restart helps, I guess it's not a hardware isse? Or could that still be one? How can I investigate the problem?

Comment: Most likely issue is power management. That can be hardware but the kernel is also allowed to disable usb when -not in use- so that seems less likely. Also check your BIOS for USB power settings. IIRC you can use `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/<your device>/power/control` to view the current settings.

Comment: Can power management also be the issue when my laptop is plugged in all the time?

Comment: Yes inactivity is the key here. "Doing nothing" can be a trigger to power down USB.

Comment: It once happened while I was in a video conference ... and I keep clicking on mute / unmute. So I guess that is not the case. Then it's pretty certain the hardware, right?